# As a QA is it necessary to learn all frameworks in Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-design, test-automation-framework

Currently, I am working as a Test Engineer. I want to know something about selenium Framework.

I am using page object & page factory design pattern in my project. I don't have knowledge about various frameworks like data driven framework, hybrid and keyword drive framework.

As a Test Engineer my question is:
Should I learn all frameworks?
Should I practice with all frameworks?
or
Only following page object & page factory design pattern ?
In future I should learn all selenium frameworks. 
When I go to an interview should they ask to automate this scenario using particular selenium frameworks.

I working as tester in my company there were 10 employees are there and I am only tester in my company. So I learning selenium alone. In my company nobody knows about testing. So please help me to give a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always keep in mind [YAGNI](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html) (You Aren't Gonna Need It) with your production tests, because just implementing frameworks since they exist is a bad-guidence.

Start thinking about what you want to test. Now if you have something that you cannot test with your current tools and frameworks you can start and do desk research how others have solved this. Personally for end-2-end type tests I have never really had a need for anything more than Selenium and the PageObject model.

Though knowledge of [Clean Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882) and design patterns might help to make the test-suite more readable, maintainable and extendable.

If you have the time be sure to read testing blogs/books and try testing frameworks experiments, but don't just blindly start using them in your production tests.

I would advice you try to improve your testing and programming knowledge a little bit every day.